# Elastic Search Conditional Aggregation on Nested Type

Tags: elasticsearch

lets say i have this kind of data

```
{
    "name": "john",
    "year_count_filter": {
        "2018": {
            "0" : 0,
            "1" : 0,
            "2" : 1,
        },
        "2019" : {
            "0" : 1,
            "1" : 1,
            "2" : 1,

        }
    }
}
```

i wanted to search sum of 2018.1 , 2018.2 , and 2019.* (all child of 2019) is bigger than 2. is it possible to do that in elasticsearch ? or do i need to process that in other programing language like python to get what i wanted ?

thanks.

Comment: Add mapping of index as well.